# Add text and image to MultiColumnLayout in borb library

Tags: python, borb

I am new to this library.
I want to create "newspaper lookalike" page with this library.

I want to add headline, lead, text and image to the pdf file. Text is very long so i want to use MultiColumnLayout.
I also want to set up the margins and spacing between the columns.
Are there any explanations, code snippets for this?
When every I copy/paste the code that I find on the internet, I get some kind of error, like code is updated.

I have this code, but I do not have a clue how to add text, margins, column spacing or even image:

```
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import MultiColumnLayout

# create an empty PDF
Document = Document()

# create an empty Page
Page = Page()
doc.add_page(page)

# set a PageLayout
PageLayout = MultiColumnLayout(page, 
                               column_widths=[w - Decimal(100)], 
                               margin_top=Decimal(50), 
                               margin_right=Decimal(50),
                               margin_bottom=Decimal(50),
                               margin_left=Decimal(50),
                                )
```

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`

Let's go over your code

The imports are fine for now.
You will need more imports if you want to add content, but we'll get to that.

```
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import MultiColumnLayout
```

Next we create an empty `Document`. The `Document` class represents a PDF.
It would be better if you did not name your variables after classes.

```
# create an empty PDF
doc = Document()
```

One thing I would also do is to add type hints. But that's completely optional.

Next we add an empty `Page` to the `Document` we made.
Again, don't name your variables after classes.

```
# create an empty Page
page = Page()
doc.add_page(page)
```

Next we use a `PageLayout`. `MultiColumnLayout` is an instance of `PageLayout` that will split a `Page` into several columns, and flow content from one column to the next when needed.

**Again, do not name variables after existing classes.**

```
# determine the width of a single column
column_width = (Decimal(595) - Decimal(100)) // Decimal(2)

# determine the margin between columns
inter_column_margin: Decimal = Decimal(5)
column_width -= inter_column_margin

# set a PageLayout
layout = MultiColumnLayout(page,
                           column_widths=[column_width, column_width],
                           inter_column_margins=[inter_column_margin],
                           margin_top=Decimal(50),
                           margin_right=Decimal(50),
                           margin_bottom=Decimal(50),
                           margin_left=Decimal(50),
                          )
```

Now we can add some content!

```py
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import Lipsum

for _ in range(0, 20):
    layout.add(Paragraph(Lipsum.generate_lipsum_text(5)))
```

And finally we can store the `Document`

```py
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as in_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(in_file_handle, doc)
```

Or, the complete example in 1 snippet:

```
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout
from borb.pdf import MultiColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import Paragraph

# create an empty PDF
doc = Document()

# create an empty Page
page = Page()
doc.add_page(page)

# determine the width of a single column
column_width = (Decimal(595) - Decimal(100)) // Decimal(2)

# determine the margin between columns
inter_column_margin: Decimal = Decimal(5)
column_width -= inter_column_margin

# set a PageLayout
layout = MultiColumnLayout(
    page,
    column_widths=[column_width, column_width],
    inter_column_margins=[inter_column_margin],
    margin_top=Decimal(50),
    margin_right=Decimal(50),
    margin_bottom=Decimal(50),
    margin_left=Decimal(50),
)

# add content
for _ in range(0, 20):
    layout.add(Paragraph(Lipsum.generate_lipsum_text(5)))


# store
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as in_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(in_file_handle, doc)
```

which yields the following PDF:

[image]

If you need more examples, check out the [examples repository](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples/).